# RStudio Ctrl shortcut not working as expected

Tags: r, rstudio

I've just downloaded RStudio 1.3.959 and I would like to set a shortcut to "Ctrl + R, but when I type it, it's set as "Ctrl + □". 
[image]

It's the same issue with every letters, some are set as "□" others as blank, and for example "Ctrl + h" is set as "Ctrl + backspace" and "Ctrl + m" is set as "Ctrl + enter". It looks like it only affects shortcuts using Ctrl. For example "shift + r" or "alt + r" are working fine.

Any idea on what is going wrong ?

I don't know if it matters but I'm using an AZERTY keyboard.

Comment: This is a bug. I've issued that today at github, you may comment/upvote/else there. See: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7014

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug with the IDE not solvable by the SO community.